# Unable to see error in test.log in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having problem to generate a log to see the error of page break in `log/test.log`

Everything is generating except page break issue.

I have a project running on aws
when I start puma server using 
**bundle exec puma -e production -d -b unix:///tmp/run/pokerstop.sock**
and generate log with **tail -f log/production.log** commands
I can see my production log
but when I start my puma sever in test environment and check log using
 **tail -f log/test.log** command nothing comes out

sometime page goes break on server and I want check cause of page break in test server but nothing comes out

Please help me
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not quite specific enough. Please post the code you think is not working, the actual result and what you would expect. That way we may be able to help. Btw: the logs are written to if "something" runs your app with the appropriate environment settings. For `development.log` and `production.log` these are usually servers, for `test.log` it is usually your tests which you invoke by `rake test` (or `bundle exec rake test` if you are using `bundler` as you should).

Answer (score 1):

Do you expect your rails app to be run in a test environment like development and production..?

If so, run your rails server in test environment as follows:

```
rails s -e test
```

You should see the logs of your application in /log/test.log file.

Also, make sure you have added database configuration for test environment in database.yml file.

Hope this helps you.!!